# Declaring method return type Task<int> without async keyword

Tags: c#, async-await, task

In what situation would you return a `Task<T>` without using `async` in the method signature?

I've got such a method in the below code but am having trouble understanding what's going on.

Why does my example code below not execute past any of the `await` statements?
ie. why do `Console.WriteLine("4)");` and `Console.WriteLine("3)");` and `return x;` never get executed?

```
class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            TestAsync testAsync = new TestAsync();
            testAsync.Run();

            Console.Read();
        }
    }

    public class TestAsync
    {
        public async void Run()
        {
            Task<int> resultTask = GetInt();
            Console.WriteLine("2)");
            int x = await resultTask;
            Console.WriteLine("4)");
        }
        public async Task<int> GetInt()
        {
            Task<int> GetIntAfterLongWaitTask = GetIntAfterLongWait();
            Console.WriteLine("1)");
            int x = await GetIntAfterLongWaitTask;
            Console.WriteLine("3)");
            return x;
        }

        public Task<int> GetIntAfterLongWait()
        {            
            Task.Run(() =>
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < 500000000; i++)
                {
                    if (i % 10000000 == 0)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine(i);
                    }
                }
            });

            Console.WriteLine("Returning 23");
            return new Task<int>(() => 23);
        }
    }

/*
Output is:
Returning 23
1)
2)
<list of ints>
*/
```

Comment: `Task<T>` is a legitimate type that can be returned by any method. If it doesn't have the `async` keyword in front then you simply cannot `await` something in the method.

Comment: But then why doesn't the compiler give a warning/compilation error?

Comment: You use it if your method just needs to return a task without needing to await it itself, e.g. because it is the last statement in a method. That being said you should generally never use `new Task`. If you want to return a value wrapped as task, i.e. a completed task result, use `Task.FromResult(23)` which has the advantage of not using up a thread like `Task.Run` and probably `new Task`.

Comment: @Backwards_Dave - The compiler doesn't give a warning or error because it is valid code.

Comment: I'm curious, where did you sea using the `Task<T>` constructor as a practice?

Comment: [The `Task` constructor has literally zero use cases](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2014/05/a-tour-of-task-part-1-constructors.html).

Comment: @Enigmativity I thought you can only await a method which is defined as async, but the compiler doesn't complain if you await a method that is not async but returns a Task. So you can await any method that is either marked async, or not marked as async but returns a Task?

Comment: You can only `await` calls **within** a method where that method is marked `async`. It has nothing to do with what the method you are **calling** is marked as.

Comment: @Backwards_Dave - Have a read of https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/pfxteam/2011/01/13/await-anything/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem in your code is that you are actually `await` never started task since the method `GetIntAfterLongWait` returns new instance of the task which is not started. So basically you have a deadlock, waiting for something which is not started at all.

You could return `Task.FromResult(23)` which is basically already completed task, or you could actually run your task `Task.Run<int>(() => 23);`

Comment: It’s not recommended to use `Task.Factory.StartNew` (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.taskfactory.startnew?view=netframework-4.7.2#remarks) except in special cases which this case isn’t one of them.

Answer (score 6):

**When you return a `Task` from a non-`async` method?**

`Task<T>` is generalized spoken a *promise* for a *future* value. Whether you produce this promise from an `async` keyworded method or from another source (like a started thread or IO callbacks) is not of interest for the caller and only an implementation strategy. That is also the reason, why interfaces (or abstract method definition) do not have the `async` keyword at all (`async`/`await` is an implementation strategy).

**Your code sample**

- **Issue 1**: Your method `GetIntAfterLongWait` is flawed in two ways. The first instantiated `Task` is instantiated and off-loaded to a thread, but the result is never picked up (so never awaited ... and never delaying anything).
- **Issue 2**: The second task (the one you return in `GetIntAfterLongWait`) is created (by the constructor with a method to execute) but not started (`Task.Start()`). Other more simplier methods are the static `Task.Run` or (in this case) `Task.FromResult`. The task (or promise) never delivers the result, because the function block in the constructor is never executed.
- **Issue 3**: The `Main` method does not await the result of the returned task (either by `await` or `Task.Wait()` or `Task.Result`.

Answer (score 0):

You are likely creating a new thread in the `GetIntAfterLongWait()` method. Try changing `return new Task<int>(() => 23);` to `return Task.FromResult(23);`.

For more information on `Task.FromResult` see the MSDN Documentation (with a good example) on [How to: Create Pre-Computed Tasks](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/parallel-programming/how-to-create-pre-computed-tasks)